# How do I choose CANCEL with a Chrome shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, chromebook

In Macintosh I use Command Period (.) for a shortcut to Cancel in a Window as an alternative to clicking on Okay.  Chrome doesn't have that for Chromebook?

Comment: Does Esc (escape) work?

Comment: Escape doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what context you are trying to cancel. Where does this window occur? The following might be helpful though

- To close a tab/window, use `ctrl+w`
- You can use `tab` to cycle through buttons in a button in a confirmation (like for unsaved changes in a website). `enter` then clicks the button that has focus.

To find more shortcuts, use `ctrl-alt-/`.

Comment: Many dialog boxes have the options to either click Okay or click Cancel.